# Can one mobile app support multiple different MDMs?

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone, enterprise, mdm

Can one mobile app support multiple different MDMs (Mobile Device Management solution i.e. Maas360, Airwatch, etc.)? For example one device controlled by MDM 'x' can install it, as well as another device controlled by MDM 'y'. Or is the logic within apps to integrate MDM's not able to differentiate between which specific MDM solution the device is controlled by?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41615056/can-a-mobile-app-which-supports-an-mdm-work-on-devices-which-do-not-run-on-mdms?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. Each SDK typically has it's own kind of `init` method so you can build the logic to `try..catch` that.

However, depending on MDM functionality you rely on and the platform you're on, that may or may not be available in all MDM solutions.

Comment: Hi Zaitsman, can you elaborate on what I should try...catch? I am reading about the Airwatch SDK if you can use that as an example